# access to multi-organizations for same user ms crm 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I've 10 CALs for MS CRM 2013 and I have 3 organizations so can I use single user for 3 organization, does it mean 1 CAL or 3 CALs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need 1 CAL, not 3 CALs for that user. The CRM 2013 User CAL is good for all CRM 2013 servers deployed within your organization.

So if your 100 employee organization deployed 4 CRM servers with 2 organizations and gave all employees access to both organizations you would need 4 server licenses and 100 User CALs.

See page 7 of this PDF: https://partner.microsoft.com/download/global/40196599